# Return a list item from a null value using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm using a list comprehension to get a list of numerical values that are separated by a semicolon, `;`, within a string.

I need to get a 0 from missing values on either side of the semicolon.

Example string without missing values:

```
   job_from_serial_st = 'xxxxx\rxxxxxx\rxxxx\rGAX=77.00;85.00\rxxxxx\r'
```

Using my list comprehension I would get the following list of values: `[7700, 8500]`

But how can I get a list of values from strings like `'GAX=77.00;\r'` or `'GAX=;85.00\r'`?

I'm expecting to get the following lists from the example strings with missing values:

`[7700, 0]` or `[0, 8500]`

```
def get_term(A, B, phrase):   

    n = A.len()
    start = phrase.find(A) + n
    end = phrase.find(B, start)
    term = phrase[start:end]

    return term


# GET GAX NUMBER 
gax_nums = get_term(r'GAX=', r'\r\x1e\x1d', job_from_serial_st)
gax = [int(float(x) * 100) for x in gax_nums.split(';')]
print(gax)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition to the list comprehension to return 0 if there is no number before or after the semicolon (also replaced your function with a series of splits to retrieve the numbers from the string).

```
s = 'xxxxx\rxxxxxx\rxxxx\rGAX=77.00;\rxxxxx\r'
nums = s.split('GAX=')[1].split('\r')[0].split(';')

gax = [int(float(n) * 100) if n else 0 for n in nums]

print(gax)
# [7700, 0]
```